# Recurrent problem about polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given is a sequence of polynomials $P_n$, defined as follows: $P_0(x)=0, P_{n+1}(x) = P_n(x) + \frac{x-P_n^2(x)}{2}. $, n= 0,1,2,..., and x is real.

Proving that for all non-negative integers n and x at [0;1] this holds:

$0\leq \sqrt(x)-P_n(x) \leq \frac{2}{n+1}  . $.

I checked for small cases n=0,1,2 the hypothesis, and it turns out true fot all x at [0;1]! But how do we proceed? Setting some recurrence? I tried induction, but can't find ties.

Comment: make the substitution $Q_n(x) = \sqrt{x} - P_n(x)$ [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822495/) and you'll get $Q_0(x)=0, Q_{n+1}(x) = Q_n(x) + \frac{x-Q_n^2(x)}{2}$, the answers already established stronger inequalities on upperbound of $Q_n(x)$ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first I prove right hand:

let $$a_{n}=\sqrt{x}-P_{n}(x)$$
then we have
$$a_{n+1}(x)=a_{n}(x)\left[1-\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+P_{n}(x)}{2}\right]
\le a_{n}(x)\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right),x\in[0,1]$$
so
$$a_{n}(x)\le a_{0}\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^n
=\sqrt{x}\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^n$$
note
$$g(t)=t\left(1-\dfrac{t}{2}\right)^n\le\dfrac{2}{n+1}$$
because we let
$$f(x)=\ln{x}+n\ln{(1-\dfrac{x}{2})}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{n}{x-2}=0$$
$$x=\dfrac{2}{n+1}$$
so
$$g(t)=t(1-\dfrac{t}{2})^n\le t=\dfrac{2}{n+1},0<t$$
so we have
$$a_{n}(x)\le\dfrac{2}{n+1}$$

and the left is clear

Comment: After "then we have", is it $1-\dfrac{x+P_{n}(x)}{2}$ or $1-\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+P_{n}(x)}{2}$ ?

Comment: Beauty And mathematical gourgeousness

Comment: How do you prove that line with the g function?

Comment: @Jackie one can use $\displaystyle g(t) = t\left(1-\frac{t}{2}\right)^n \le \frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{\frac{nt}{2}+n\left(1-\frac{t}{2}\right)}{n+1}\right)^n = \frac{2}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}$ from Am-Gm inequality, and since $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} \ge e$, we get $\displaystyle g(t) \le \frac{2}{ne}$.