# Does this sequence of polynomials converge to the square root function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Taken from Lang's R & F Analysis (p.60). For some reason I can't see why, for $t \in [0,1]$, the following is true for all natural numbers $n$ (by an inductive argument):
$$0 \leq \sqrt{t} - P_n(t) \leq \frac{2\sqrt{t}}{2 + n\sqrt{t}},$$
where
$$P_{n+1}(t) = P_n(t) +\frac{1}{2}\left(t-P_n(t)^2\right),$$
and $P_0(t) = 0$.

Comment: There is no explanation in the book?

Comment: @Crostul Nope, it's actually an exercise (problem 7 in $\text{III, §4}$).

Comment: Are you interested in a more intuitive solution to finding such a function, or are you set on using this method to define a sequence of polynomials?

Comment: @TrialAndError I am just interested in this method. In particular, I feel that there should be a relatively straightforward inductive proof for this problem, but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: Substitute $\sqrt{x} - P_n(x) = Q_n(x)$ which satisfies the same recursion as here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822495/show-that-p-nx-rightrightarrows-0-qquad-x-in0-1

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I answer. I have a very similar problem in proving stone weierstrass. 
Those sequence of polynomials in $[0,1]$ converge to square root function from below. Show inductevely that they are less than the square root, and show they for a fixed $x$ the sequence $p_n(x)$ is increasing, and thus has a limit, and the limit has to satisfy a equation analogus to the definition of the recursion of $ P_n$. That suffices to prove that they converge square root function from below, that possibly helps. I know it doesn't solve the exercise.